Why these 2 scripts give different results?
Below 2 scripts give a different sets of result. The difference between them is only in the order of joins and the 1st table from which I take the results. Since these are inner joins, why does it matter?
SELECT
    ing.ingredientname,
    me.measurementdescription,
    'default' AS measurement_type
FROM
    recipesexample.ingredients ing
    JOIN recipesexample.measurements me ON me.measureamountid = ing.measureamountid
UNION
SELECT
    ing.ingredientname,
    me.measurementdescription,
    'recipe' AS measurement_type
FROM
    recipesexample.ingredients ing
    JOIN recipesexample.measurements me ON me.measureamountid = ing.measureamountid
    JOIN recipesexample.recipe_ingredients ri ON ri.ingredientid = ing.ingredientid;


SELECT
    ing.ingredientname,
    me.measurementdescription,
    'default' AS measurement_type
FROM recipesexample.measurements me
    JOIN recipesexample.ingredients ing ON me.measureamountid = ing.measureamountid
UNION
SELECT
    ing.ingredientname,
    me.measurementdescription,
    'recipe' AS measurement_type
FROM recipesexample.measurements me
    JOIN recipesexample.recipe_ingredients ri ON me.measureamountid = ri.measureamountid
    JOIN recipesexample.ingredients ing ON ing.ingredientid = ri.ingredientid;

I thought that they should give the same results but after using UNION sets have different number of rows.

The order of the results is always undefined when using SQL, unless you specify an ORDER BY.

I cannot imagine the results to have a different number of rows. The queries are equivalent. Maybe rows got inserted, updated or deleted after you ran one query and before running the second?

I've tried to run queries one by one for a few times so there's no chance that that the rows had been updated.

Please read How to make en example and allow people to replicate your issue rather than just letting them guess. You can for example use https://dbfiddle.uk/S9ZOHCkV

@Luuk: The order or rows is irrelevant to this question.

@ErwinBrandstetter: According to the title ("Why these 2 scripts give different results?") it is not irrelevant.

@Luuk: Agreed. Only the final question mentions the number of rows.

Yes, I've meant the number of rows, not order. I guess I need to be more exact in my future questions, thanks!

Both queries are equivalent and must return exactly the same number of rows.
(The order of result rows can vary without outer ORDER BY, even between calls of the same query.)
Related:

Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?

If you observe a different number of result rows (and this cannot stem from concurrent activity), something is broken in your database.
Might be a corrupted index. Try REINDEX on all involved tables.
(Remember to have regular backups if your data is important.)
